# alert success and alert danger message buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am working on hard to get this done but couldn't find how to do it

i have a code with two buttons yes and no. what i am trying to do is once i clicked on yes button the success message should print on the page(not popup)the same way no button also should display a message. is there anyway to do it with javascript or bootstrap?

confirmation.component.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{confirmationMessage}}</p>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success" (click)="emitAction(true)">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="emitAction(false)">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

confirmation.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation',
  templateUrl: './confirmation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() action:EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
  @Input() confirmationMessage;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  emitAction(isConfirmed:Boolean){
    this.action.emit(isConfirmed)
  }

}
```

users.component.html

```
<div class="container">   <h2>Active Users</h2>   <hr>   <table datatable  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="!showLoader">
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>{{user.local.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.local.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <div *ngIf="user.local.sub_end_dt && (user.local.sub_end_dt| amDifference : dateTo : 'days')>=0">
            <span style="color: green;">{{(user.local.sub_end_dt| amDifference : dateTo : 'days')>=0?"Active":""}}</span>
            <br>
            <span>{{(user.local.sub_end_dt| amDifference : dateTo : 'days')}} Days Remaining</span>
          </div>
          <span style="color: red;">{{(user.local.sub_end_dt| amDifference : dateTo : 'days')<0||!user.local.sub_end_dt?"Expired":""}}</span>  
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="copyPassword(user.local.password)" title="Copy Password"></i>
          |<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="setAction('delete',user,'Do you wish to delete the user?')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal"  style="color: red; cursor: pointer;" title="Delete User"></i>
          |<i class="fa fa-ban" *ngIf="user.local.sub_active" (click)="setAction('disable',user,'Do you wish to disable the user?')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal"  aria-hidden="true" style="color: orange;cursor: pointer;" title="Disable User" ></i>
          <i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="!user.local.sub_active" (click)="setAction('enable',user,'Do you wish to enable the user?')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal"  aria-hidden="true" style="color: green;cursor: pointer;" title="Enable User"></i>
          |<i class="fa fa-user-secret" *ngIf="!user.admin" (click)="setAction('enableAdmin',user,'Do you wish to grant admin role to user?')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Make User Admin"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-user" style="color: grey;cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="user.admin" (click)="setAction('disableAdmin',user,'Do you wish to disable admin access for user?')"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal" title="Disable Admin User" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          |<i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="color: blue;cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="!user.support" (click)="setAction('enableSupport',user,'Do you wish to assign support to user?')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal"  title="Assign Support"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal" style="color: orange;cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="user.support" (click)="setAction('disableSupport',user,'Do you wish to disable support for user?')" title="Disable Support"></i>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="showLoader">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div> </div> <app-confirmation (action)="action($event)" [confirmationMessage]="message"></app-confirmation>
```

Comment: And where exactly are you using this `confirmation` component? Can you please add the template for that component as well?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera i have added that component aswell

Comment: Not sure to have understood, you would like to print some message in users.component.html after yes or no?

Comment: yes after clicking yes or no button some message should be displayed in the users.component page

Comment: You'll have to define a method named action in your users.component.html. That would take this event object and set a property inside your users.component.ts to the value of the boolean wrapped inside it. And then you'll have to use that property with `*ngIf` inside your users.component.html.

Comment: i just need a function for yes button after clicking it.. i need an alert success message for it can this be done if so please guide me to how can i do it

Comment: Answered, that's one way. There's many way to do it, but in the end you always have to pass some info from child component with Output to the father component and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new model:

```
export class ConfirmationMessage{
message: string;
result: boolean;
}
```

in confirmation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationMessage } from ./confirmation-message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation',
  templateUrl: './confirmation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() action:EventEmitter<ConfirmationMessage> = new EventEmitter<ConfirmationMessage>();
  @Input() confirmationMessage;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  emitAction(isConfirmed:Boolean){
    confirmation: ConfirmationMessage = new ConfirmationMessage();
    confirmation.result = isConfirmed;
    if(isConfirmed)
       confirmation.message ="ok";
    else
       confirmation.message = "no";
    this.action.emit(confirmation);
  }

}
```

In users.component.html

```
 <app-confirmation (action)="actionElaborate($event)" [confirmationMessage]="message"></app-confirmation>
...
<p >{{messageToShow}}</p> //here to show an alert you can use bootstrap alert and show it or not with ngIf
```

in users.component.ts

```
private messageToShow: string = "";

actionElaborate(ev){
   if(ev != null){
     this.messageToShow = "";    
   }else{
      ...
      confirmation: ConfirmationMessage = ev;
      this.messageToShow = confirmation.message;
   }

}
```